# Break text lines for responsiveness

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an image with some text next to it, Both image and text are centered inside `wrapper` with width `70%`.

On different screen sizes specially the small ones, The text goes beneath the image.

I want to keep the text next to the image and when the screen becomes smaller the text would break into more lines to fit the width.

Here is the code:

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="pull-left" src="http://placehold.it/200">
    <div class="pull-left text-left">
        <h4>Lorem Lorem <br>
        Lorem Lorem
        </h4>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, <br> sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore <br> magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <br>
        </span>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, <br> sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore <br> magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <br>
        </span>
    </div> <!-- .pull-left -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div> <!-- .wrapper -->
```

Here is a fiddle to view and test the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/u8ajq2oh/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle without the use of bootstrap for your needs.

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/rmufb8L9/

```css
.wrapper{
  margin-left: 15%;
 width: 70%;
 display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  
}

img{height:min-content}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
 <img  src="http://placehold.it/200">
 <div class="text-left">
   <h4>Lorem Lorem <br>
 Lorem Lorem</h4>
   <span>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, <br> sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore <br> magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <br>
   </span>
   <span>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, <br> sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore <br> magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, <br>
   </span>
 </div>
</div>
```